# Doing operations with result from functions (AVG,MIN,MAX) on POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `test` which has only one column `pred`.

I want to feature scale those values between [a,b], which in this case is 0 and 7.

Thus, I need to do the following operation:

```
Pn = a+(p - min(p))*(b-a)/(max(p)-min(p))
```

When I try:

```
select (p-min(p))*(7)/(max(p)-min(p)) from test
```

It gives that error:

> SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "test.p" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>
> Position: 9

The code to create the same table is down below:

```
create table test(
    p float
);
insert into test
values
    (2),
    (1),
    (3),
    (5),
    (2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate functions require all non-aggregated columns to appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. You could use window functions instead of regular aggregate functions:

```
select 
    p, 
    (p-min(p) over())*(7)/(max(p) over() -min(p) over()) p_scale
from test
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e9WQhoQBmSJvKkryYDoZX5/1)**:

```
| p   | p_scale |
| --- | ------- |
| 2   | 1.75    |
| 1   | 0       |
| 3   | 3.5     |
| 5   | 7       |
| 2   | 1.75    |
```

---

To cast the results to an integer:

```
select 
    p, 
    ((p-min(p) OVER())*(7)/(max(p) over() -min(p) over()))::int p_scale
from test
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e9WQhoQBmSJvKkryYDoZX5/2)**:

```
| p   | p_scale |
| --- | ------- |
| 2   | 2       |
| 1   | 0       |
| 3   | 4       |
| 5   | 7       |
| 2   | 2       |
```

Comment: Welcome @IurySousa, happy to help!

Comment: I was trying to accept it, but I had to wait some minutes.